# Changing cv::Mat with image copied from buffer affects original image

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have image buffer in 24bit RGB format. This buffer is copied to cv::Mat using

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(image->height, image->width, CV_8UC3, image->data);
```

Since this buffer is in RGB format and OpenCV uses BGR format, I'm converting `mat`to BGR with

```
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_RGB2BGR);
```

This works, but when I check original image its channels are inverted as well (and so they become wrong) and I don't want this to happen.

I'd like to invert `mat` channels order leaving `image-data` (my image buffer) untouched. How can I do that?

Comment: Is it a problem for you to hard-copy the matrix before colour conversion or just cv::cvtColor(mat, mat2, CV_RGB2BGR); ?

Comment: I don't think so. Would it impact too much on performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume (I am not certain) that if you use `cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_RGB2BGR);`, you actually recreate mat, but you overwrite data with the RGB->BGR converted data. Since you pass data to your "mat" using pointer, if you overwrite the data in mat, you change "image->data" as well.

Therefore, I do not expect less performance than:

```
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(image->height, image->width, CV_8UC3, image->data);
cv::Mat mat2;
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat2, CV_RGB2BGR);
//Work with mat 2 now
```

Rather than overwriting, you write new data. This should bear the same performance cost... 
I do not know what plan to do with your image  after colour conversion, but even if the performance was different, it is likely to have an overall minor impact.